# How to subtract Fields.Items.Value from otherFields.Items.Value

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Using Classic ASP, VBScript and SQL, I created two record sets CY & LY which provide current year results (number) and last year results (number). I want to subtract CY - LY and display the results on a Web form only for reference and not for input and I get a mismatch error. my syntax is:

```
<td><%=(CY.Fields.Item("Result").Value) - (LY.Fields.Item("Result").Value)%></td>
```

Any guidance or help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<%=Cint(CY.Fields.Item("Result").Value) - Cint(LY.Fields.Item("Result").Value)%>
```

Comment: Or CLng() instead of CInt() if the value exceeds -32,768 to 32,767

Comment: Thank you so much - I'll give that a try - I actually was able to use get a Dim CHG = CDbl(CY.Fields.Item("Result").Value) - CDbl(LY.Fields.Item("Result").Value